# Kotlin: How to get Custom Intent in Broadcast?

Tags: android, kotlin

I create `Custom Intent` as below.

```
Intent().also { intent ->
    intent.setAction("STEP_COUNT_NOTIFICATION")
    intent.putExtra("stepCount", todayTotalStepCount)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

And I add this Custom Intent in my Broadcast Receiver tag of `AndroidManifest`.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.BroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.chungchunon.chunchunon_android.STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Since I use two Intent, one is official intent and the other is custom, I need to distinguish received Intent.

`onReceive` function of `BroadcastReceiver`

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val intentAction = intent!!.action
        when (intentAction) {
            Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED -> {
//                todayTotalStepCount = 0
                var todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf<String, Int?>(
                    "todayStepCount" to 0
                )
                userDB
                    .document("$userId")
                    .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())
            }
            
            ???? ->

        }
    }
```

How can I get STEP_COUNT_NOTIFICATION which is my custom intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a `public` constant for your custom `action`:

```
 companion object {
        const val ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION = "com.chungchunon.chunchunon_android.STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION"
 }
```

For your `Intent`, use the same `action`:

```
Intent().also { intent ->
    intent.setAction(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION)
    intent.putExtra("stepCount", todayTotalStepCount)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

Also, use the same `action` in your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val intentAction = intent!!.action
        when (intentAction) {
            Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED -> {
//                todayTotalStepCount = 0
                var todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf<String, Int?>(
                    "todayStepCount" to 0
                )
                userDB
                    .document("$userId")
                    .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())
            }

            // Your custom action
            ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION -> { // Add your code here }

        }
    }
```

Lastly, for `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.BroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED" />

        // action should be the same as the value of ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION
        <action android:name="com.chungchunon.chunchunon_android.STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`action` name should be the same for `Intent`, `AndroidManifest.xml` and `BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Intent` action needs to match the `android:name` for the corresponding `<intent-filter>`. Yours do not.

You have:

```kotlin
intent.setAction("STEP_COUNT_NOTIFICATION")
```

This has an action string of `STEP_COUNT_NOTIFICATION`.

You also have:

```xml
        <action android:name="com.chungchunon.chunchunon_android.STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION" />
```

This has an action string of `com.chungchunon.chunchunon_android.STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION`.

Those two are not the same. They need to be the same. I recommend using `com.chungchunon.chunchunon_android.STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION` in both places.